# How can I modify the size of a varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need to know if there is any way i can modify the size of a varchar from `varchar(40)` to `varchar(60)` and also add this constraint:

```
(( CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,Date_Election_President,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) >= 730 THEN
             'NON'
        ELSE 'OUI'
   END ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the length;

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable]
ALTER COLUMN [MyColumn] VARCHAR(60)
```

As to the constraint, I suspect you're looking for a computed column. You should be able to add it like this;

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] 
ADD [NewColumn] AS CASE 
   WHEN DATEDIFF(day,Date_Election_President,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) >= 730 THEN 'NON' 
   ELSE 'OUI' 
END
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf896/1).

Comment: tnks @Joachim Isaksson ,i did have  the column that i need to add the constraint in it .. not new column

Comment: @Yassineedouiri Not sure you can actually have time based constraints, since time changes you may end up with contraints that aren't true for data already in the table. What would you like to achieve with it? If you want to validate that the value is correct at insert time, why not just calculate it on insert instead of making a constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Query and run it on query board

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] 
ALTER COLUMN [ColumnName] VARCHAR(60)
```